Subtracting a value from a float in C# and adding it back does not give the original value
for context: i am trying to determine two angles, that when both added together d times, equal 6.28319 radians (or 360 degrees). Below is my code, where I calculate dTheta (6.28319 radians divided by d), smallThetaTeeth (an angle that cant imagine is specifically relevant to this problem), and bigThetaTeeth, which is merely dTheta - smallThetaTeeth.
    float dTheta = Mathf.PI * 2.0f / d;
    
    Debug.Log("dTheta: " + dTheta);

    float smallThetaTeeth = Mathf.PI - 2 * (Mathf.Acos((t / 2) / tr));
    float bigThetaTeeth = dTheta - smallThetaTeeth;

    Debug.Log("small + big theta teeth: " + smallThetaTeeth + bigThetaTeeth);

in theory, adding smallThetaTeeth and bigThetaTeeth together should result in dTheta. However as evidenced by my debug statements, it doesn't!! and instead results in some strange number with two decimal points?? any help would be appreciated.
debug statements
I am aware floats are less precise than doubles, and have already tried these same equations using doubles rather than floats, to the exact same result.

For the second problem, because you start with a string in Debug.Log the two numbers are added as strings - use parentheses to do the math first: Debug.Log("small + big theta teeth: " + (smallThetaTeeth + bigThetaTeeth));

Debug.Log("small + big theta teeth: " + smallThetaTeeth + bigThetaTeeth);

This line should be:
Debug.Log("small + big theta teeth: " + (smallThetaTeeth + bigThetaTeeth));

or:
Debug.Log(string.Format("small + big theta teeth: {0}", smallThetaTeeth + bigThetaTeeth));

Recall that + is left-associative, so your expression is being interpreted as ("small + big theta teeth: " + smallThetaTeeth) + bigThetaTeeth.  So you have two string + number concatenations rather than adding the numbers.

While the imprecision of floating math operation is relevant, I don't think that's your problem. Your problem is you are seeing the result as the concatenation of the two numbers displayed as strings  ("0.02000046" + "0.7653977" = "0.020000460.7653977"). You need to do the math before the system convert the result (0.02000046 + 0.7653977 = 0.78539816`) to a string:
Debug.Log("small + big theta teeth: " + (smallThetaTeeth + bigThetaTeeth));

You may still see tiny differences between the result and dTheta, but I don't think that was the source of your confusion.

I guess the problem here is that you're assuming floating point addition to be commutative (dTheta - smallThetaTeeth + smallThetaTeeth == dTheta + smallThetaTeeth - smallThetaTeeth). That is definitely not the case.
Floating point addition, be it float or double or anything, is neither commutative nor associative. In fact, not even simple algebra axioms hold true when ran on a discrete CPU, things like a + b == a + b, if they run in different precision contexts.
Simply write better code that doesn't rely on such falsehoods (tm)!

Floating-point addition is commutative (aside from propagating NaNs); a+b gives the same result as b+a. Changing dTheta - smallThetaTeeth + smallThetaTeeth to dTheta + smallThetaTeeth - smallThetaTeeth could be consider a reassociation if you take some liberties, but it does not demonstrate any failure of operands to commute.
